# background image not displaying inside div

Tags: html, css

Trying to make a landing page at work. For some reason a background image isnt displaying here is the relevant html and css.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="top-bar">

        <div class="top-bar-left"><img src="img/AzlanLogo.png"></div>
        <div class="top-bar-right"><img src="img/MicrosoftLogo.png"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="header-container">
    <div class="header-left"></div>

    <div class="header-right"><p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Download file</a></p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg right" href="#" role="button">E-mail to friend</a></p></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.header-container {
    background-image: url('img/bg-header.png');
    height: 229px;
    width: 1013px;
    margin: 0px auto;

}

.header-left {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}

.header-right {
    width: 70%;
    float: right;
}
```

checked in google dev tools and the image url is correct. Though, i cant figure out why the image doesnt display ?

Hope that gives sufficient information for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I link to my own asset your code seems to work.

It is more than likely your path to the asset is incorrect, try adding the full domain to the rule:

`background-image: url('http://www.yourdomainhere.com/img/bg-header.png');`

If that doesn't work post the `<head>` contents for debugging.

Comment: Thanks, it was a local version. But i now uploaded the files to a server and used an absolute link. Seemed to do the trick. Unsure as to why but meh. :)

Comment: This is surely not something to meh about. You should always try NOT to use full sitepaths in image source property. Especially if you are referrencing to an image from an external server, this is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

If the code You have provided is online, stored on a web hosting or being edited locally on a XAMPP/MAMP etc. server, your image path should be as follows:

> **NOTE:** This is meant to be applied in your HTML. In CSS, your current default url() should be working just fine.

```
<img src="../img/AzlanLogo.png">
```

The `../` before `img/AzlanLogo.png` tells the browser to go back and search in the main directory for your `img` folder, then find the specified file.

Comment: did try that too. :)

Comment: Are you sure the files were available or uploaded at the moment of trial?

Comment: very sure of it, the google console showed the image when i hovered over the link. It just wasnt showing up for whatever reason.